# Is there a DocBook reader for following in-progress documents?

Tags: pdf, convert

I have `docbook2pdf` installed, but it seems a bit wasteful to always need to delete and re-create the .PDF file when the source changes. Is there a good program for styling and viewing them natively?

Answer (score 1):

Once I created a huge technical specification and used XMLMind for editing the source file in DocBook format. For conversion to Pdf used some java tool.
[source](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/screenshots.html)

Comment: I'm aware of a great number of tools for converting to pdf, etc; I was  hoping for something that would allow me to render from source in real time.